# Mean of one numerical variable against two categorical variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

My df has three variables. NSCore , NS_Group (which is categorical, have three levels Low,High,Very High). SOC(Which is categorical having three levels SOC1,SOC2 and SOC3). Looking like that.

```
df
NScore   NS_group   SOC
1      Low      SOC1
2      Low      SOC2
3      High     SOC3
4      High     SOC2
5      Very High SOC3
```

I am using following code in R But this is giving me frequency of NScore against NS_group and SOC . But i want to see the mean of NScore against these two.

```
 `tab1 <- with(df, table(df$NS_group,df$SOC))
```

I want MEAN OF NScore (Not the frequency) against these two categories something as follows.

```
          SOC1  SOC2  SOC3
Low        1     1     2
High       1     2     1
VeryHigh   1     1     2
```

p.s All the values are hypothtical just to explain what i am asking

Answer (score 0):

If you want a base R solution use this:

```
aggregate(SOC ~ NS_group, df, mean)
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not working as both SOC and NS_group are categorical. I would like to ass that NS_group is actually based on NScore. Like people having NScore 0-2 are categorized as Low.

Comment: well just add `as.numeric(SOC)` because means of (unordered) factors don't really make sense